# unhandles exception error when login page idle

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have developed a site in vb.net (with some help from my brother in law) and it's almost ready to roll out except I am getting an unhandled exception error on the login
screen when the page is idle for a few minutes.  I am reasonably new to vb.net and not a programmer :( Any help would be really appreciated.  Sorry if anything in my post is not to the site standard as this is my first post. :)

I'm not sure why this is happening.  The code that is executed on login_buttonClick is:

`Protected Sub LoginWizard_FinishButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles LoginWizard.FinishButtonClick`

```
    Dim oUsername As String = txtUsername.Text
    Dim oPassword As String = txtPassword.Text

    Dim oPath As String = Server.MapPath("App_Data/IOFR.mdb")
    Dim oValid As Boolean = False

    Dim oReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = Nothing
    Dim oConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = Nothing

    Dim oName As String = ""
    Dim oOrg As String = ""
    Dim oUserId As Integer = 0
    Dim oActiveAcc As String = ""
    Dim oSessionExpire As Integer = 0

    Try
        oConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=EdmundColin13", oPath))
        oConnection.Open()

        Dim ipAddress As String = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        Dim oParams As New List(Of System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter)
        oParams.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@pmUsername", oUsername))
        oParams.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@pmPassowrd", oPassword))

        Dim oCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT ID, [Name], Organisation, ActiveAccount, [Password] FROM Users WHERE [Username] = @pmUsername AND [Password] = @pmPassword", oConnection)
        oCommand.Parameters.AddRange(oParams.ToArray)
        oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader()

        If oReader.Read() Then
            oValid = True
            oName = oReader.GetString(oReader.GetOrdinal("Name"))
            oActiveAcc = oReader.GetString(oReader.GetOrdinal("ActiveAccount"))
            oOrg = oReader.GetString(oReader.GetOrdinal("Organisation"))
            oPassword = oReader.GetString(oReader.GetOrdinal("Password"))
            oUserId = oReader.GetInt32(oReader.GetOrdinal("ID"))
            oSessionExpire = oReader.GetInt32(oReader.GetOrdinal("SessionExpire"))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        If Not oReader Is Nothing Then
            If Not oReader.IsClosed Then
                oReader.Close()
            End If
            oReader = Nothing
        End If

    End Try
    If oValid And Not String.Equals(txtPassword.Text, oPassword) Then
        oValid = False
    End If

    If oValid Then

        If oActiveAcc = "No" Then
            Response.Redirect("~/DisabledAccount.aspx")
            Return
        End If

        Session("username") = txtUsername.Text
        Session("name") = oName
        Session("org") = oOrg

        'Generate session id and store it in session
        Dim uniquesessionid As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        Session("uid") = uniquesessionid

        Dim oCommandSession As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE Users SET SessionId = @pmid, SessionExpire = '" & DateTime.Now.AddHours(2).ToString() & "' WHERE [ID] = @pmUserid", oConnection)
        oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@pmid", uniquesessionid))
        oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@pmUserid", oUserId))
        oCommandSession.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx?login=true")
    Else
        txtUsername.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        txtUsername.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        txtPassword.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        FailedLogin.Visible = True
    End If

    If Not oConnection Is Nothing Then
        If oConnection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
            oConnection.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the exception?  Great first question btw - good job posting relevant code :)

Comment: I agree this is a great question, but which is line is the exception thrown on?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I am getting a rather long message.  The crux I think is: System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed

Comment: Try look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/464873/Validation-of-viewstate-MAC-failed. I think a better problem explanation is needed. Is it in a cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All.  This seams to have resolved the issue.
     
     
     `EnableViewStateMAC="False"`